# Android studio Run window keeps disapearing at runtime

Tags: android, android-studio

My run window keeps disappearing during whenever I rebuild and restart my app in android studio. Yes, I am well aware, I can go to View > Tool Windows > Run or Alt + 4 to restore it, but is there a way to permanently pin it there, and keep it from disappearing every time I re-run?

Comment: You might check that the "Activate tool window" option is selected in the relevant configurations under Run -> Edit Configurations…. It'll be at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue after an update in AS.

1. Run -> Edit configurations...
2. In the General tab scroll to the bottom
3. Check the "Activate tool window"